# How to get_template_directory() properly on local environment

Tags: functions, localhost, site-url

I'm currently developing a site locally in MAMP PRO. When I use get_template_directory() inside of the standard functions.php file, the site path gets output correctly. However, I have a separate enqueue.php file that I use to enqueue my scripts.

I'm using a require to include the enqueue.php file.

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/enqueue.php';
```

My issue begins inside of enqueue.php. Whenever I try to use get_template_directory(), instead of returning the correct site path, I keep getting the following output:

```
http://project.dev/Users/myuser/Sites/rouge-theme/wp-content/themes/rougeman/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js?ver=4.2
```

I can't seem to figure out why the /Users path gets added to the URL when I'm not in the functions file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to add, get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) seems to work fine. I'd like to use get_template_directory() instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_template_directory()` returns a filesystem path-- that is, it returns the path to the file as it would appear if you were browsing it on the local machine via a file browser.

> Return Values
>
> (string) 
>       Absolute path to the directory of the current theme (without the trailing slash).
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

That is what you are seeing. The function works correctly (based on my interpretation of your question, anyway).

You want [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) instead, which will give you a path relative to your web server root and [which is what `get_bloginfo('template_directory');` gives you](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).